# Seaborn: need workaround for figure margin in boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm with a weird behavior in Seaborn inside a Jupyter Notebook. I draw a list of bloxplots and it prints fine:

```
sns.boxplot(
data=df_enem, y='CO_ESCOLA', x='nota_final', orient='h', 
order=df_melhores.head(NUM_MELHORES).CO_ENTIDADE)
```

The top of the chart is fine, as you can see in this screenshot:
[image: good image]

Now I print exactly the same chart, **but get and set the `yticks`** and the figure margins are messed up:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df_enem, y='CO_ESCOLA', x='nota_final', orient='h', 
                 order=df_melhores.head(NUM_MELHORES).CO_ENTIDADE)
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
plt.yticks(locs, labels);
```

[image: messed up margins]

If I print the locs and labels variables, I get just:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39] <a list of 40 Text yticklabel objects>
```

The same problem happens at the bottom of the figure.

Any workaround to fix this figure?

Comment: Downgrading to 3.1.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to record your `ylim` before changing the `yticks` and then set it back after having changed the ticks. Something like this should work fine:

```
ylim=ax.get_ylim()    
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
plt.yticks(locs, labels)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
```

The reason behind this problem is that `lim` and `ticks` are not *independent*. The `ticks` are just discrete points within your limits. So when you set the `yticks` the limits of the graph are changed to match the first/last `ytick` element. You can see this with a simple example:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
ax = sns.boxplot(data=iris, orient="h", palette="Set2")
ylim=ax.get_ylim()
```

The ylim are: `(3.5, -0.5)`. If we now change the the `yticks` and check again the `ylim`:

```
yticks = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
ylim=ax.get_ylim()
```

we have:

```
In [38]: yticks
Out[38]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
In [39]: ylim
Out[39]: (3.0, 0.0)
```

p.s.
this is not a seaborn related issue, but is just the way matplotlib works. For more info you can check the [ticker api](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392560/how-can-i-make-xtick-different-from-xlim-in-python-matplotlib).

Comment: The workaround is fine, but the analysis here is wrong. This is due to a bug in matplotlib 3.1.1. So use any other version of matplotlib. I therefore closed as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot/56942725#56942725).